# How to issue a graceful close in both http server and browser side when time out?

Tags: http, tcp, http-headers, http-1.1

In http1.1(http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html), it says:

> When a client or server wishes to time-out it SHOULD issue a graceful close on the transport  connection. Clients and servers SHOULD both constantly watch for the other side of the transport close, and respond to it as appropriate.

MY question is : How to issue a **graceful close** in both http server and browser side when time out?

Comment: Given that it is refering to the transport layer, I imagine what it means is that you should send a TCP `FIN` packet rather than just letting the stream lapse or sending a `RST`. How you would engineer this depends on your application, are you writing a HTTP client/server or writing an application to run over HTTP, and if the latter, what architecture/framework are your using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to close the TCP-connection at any side. Connection on other side will be closed automatically.

If you want to know how to implement automatically closing:

When other side wanna close connection it send FIN at `tcp` headers. On program side your socket will be activate by `select` function and `recv` function returns will be 0. so:

```
if (recv(socket, ...) == 0) 
  closesocket(socket);
```